# SWT Syntax highlighting widget

Tags: java, swt

Anyone know of an SWT widget that can be a text editor with support for syntax highlighting? I'm aware of the StyledText widget but I'm hoping that somebody has already written some libraries so one can just specify the keywords that should be highlighted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the general principle of syntax highlighting [are using the **StyledText** Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/StyledText%201/article1.html).
[image: StyledText Widget]

The [**JavaSourcecodeViewer**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JavaSourcecodeViewer.htm) is a more advanced example.
[image]

The **[JavaViewer](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php)** is even more detailed ([source code](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.examples/src/org/eclipse/swt/examples/javaviewer/JavaViewer.java?view=co)).

Comment: Thanks --- I was hoping to find a "simplified" widget where all that would be necessary is to provide a few sets of keywords and that's it....much like the geshi syntax highlighting system used in the mediawiki

Comment: I understand. I am not sure such a custom component does exist, but I will keep looking

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into what Eclipse uses in their code editor. Because if any SWT application uses syntax highlighting, its Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is [Eclipse Colorer plug-in](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html).

I have no idea though if and how would the colorer be usable as an SWT widget.