# SWT source code editor widget

Tags: java, python, swt, syntax-highlighting

Is there any source code editor widget for SWT? I looked for a long time and nothing found... I saw that question: [SWT Syntax highlighting widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713996/swt-syntax-highlighting-widget), but I don't want to use raw StyledText widget - I need more than only syntax highlighting. I need also, for example, code completion.

I need this to give to the user ability to edit source in Python.

Comment: The somehow complicated approach is to use StyledText and catch typing to show highlighted suggestions etc.

Comment: Eclipse is written using SWT and it has got the source editor. The perfect editor. But the problem is: as far as I know, the only way to get it is separating its source from Eclipse source...

Comment: Why the hell is this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "resolved" the problem.

I used the JFace's [SourceViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/SourceViewer.html) and other things found in Google, like for example [simple syntax highlighting](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JavaSourcecodeViewer.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an eclipse plugin for editing python files (including the outline view, and other things related to eclipse). Then you install it in an empty eclipse application (without the java editor), and the user can edit these kind of files.

A link for creating editors would be [on vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html). I know there's another example on the Internet about editing xml files, but I can't find the link now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look at how `JavaEditor` is implemented in *jdt*ui* plugin. `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` is base class for most of the editors. Once you have the editor implemented, you just need to associate file extension with the editor.