# How can I create a text box in SWT to display tags?

Tags: java, tags, swt

Has anyone seen the text box in Evernote that shows list of tags the user has entered? Each tag is sorounded in a circle with a x mark to be able to remove it. Or another example is the very stackoverflow when you put a tag you can see they are in small box rather than a comma separated text.

How can I do this with java swt?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? There is no native widget in SWT which would realize exactly that type of behaviour.

Comment: You'll probably have to used a `StyledText` widget to achieve that. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/714097/1740724) is an answer that might be a good starting point.

Comment: What about other things... like JFace or do you know anything that has this sort of widget? The StyledText you mentioned is good thanks for that, I guess if there is no available plugin, I have to do it manually with that.

Comment: @user988738 There is nothing like this that I'm aware of.